# Mostrar la hora completa (hh:mm:ss) desde que el usuario inició sesión en bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

El problema de mi código es que me muestra la hora pero sin los segundos, ya que el `who -b` no me los da, tampoco encontré otro comando que me brinde ese dato.

Mi código:

```
stringHora=$(who -b | cut -d' ' -f14)
hora=$(date -d "$stringHora" "+%T")
echo Iniciaste sesion a las: $hora
```

¿Hay otra manera de obtenerlo?

Comment: date "+%H:%M:%S" puedes usar la comanda date para eso no hace falta el who la salida seria 14:09:22

Comment: @rexxarcat uso el who para obtener la hora en la que el usuario inicia la sesión, si uso solo el date tendría la hora actual de la PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta con:

```bash
stringHora="$(last --time-format=full \
    | awk \
        -v user_pty="$(ps hotty $$)" \
        -v time_column=7 \
        '$0 ~ user_pty {print $time_column;exit}')"

echo "Iniciaste sesion a las: $stringHora"
```

Lo que hace `last` es que te lee el archivo de registro de inicio de sesiones, y le pedimos que nos ponga el formato completo de tiempo.

El comando de `awk`, de forma verbosa busca por la línea que corresponda a la terminal (o pseudo terminal, "pts/") de nuestro usuario y busca la columna referente al tiempo.

Luego la imprime y, en la primera ocurrencia (el último inicio de seción), se sale.

### Update

Como comentas que tu versión de `last` no tiene la opción `--time-format`, puedes ver si tienes la opción `-F` y aplicar la misma función con `awk`:

```
stringHora="$(last -F \
    | awk \
        -v user_pty="$(ps hotty $$)" \
        -v time_column=7 \
        '$0 ~ user_pty {print $time_column;exit}')"

echo "Iniciaste sesion a las: $stringHora"
```

Comment: tiene sentido lo que me planteas, pero no me anda la opción de --time-format. ¿Será que tengo un Linux viejo?

Comment: mira me diste la idea de usar el `last`, logre obtener lo siguiente... 

`last -F | grep $(ps hotty $$) | grep logged`

Eso me arroja lo siguiente

`root     pts/1        192.168.80.1     Wed Oct 26 01:22:13 2022   still logged in`

Ya solo me queda filtrar la hora :D

Comment: No uses ni grep ni la cadena logged. Es procesamiento de más. Tan sólo con que te arroje la primera coincidencia. Puedes usar awk para eso igualito con el ejemplo que te puse. Sin ningun cambio a la parte de awk. Deja actualizo mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no existe comando asi, pero una solucion seria:

```bash
date > dat.txt
```

Hacer que este script se ejecute al iniciar sesión y guarde dicha informacion en un fichero para luego recuperarla de ahi.

Comment: Es que el ejercicio no admite esto como solución.

Comment: mmmmm......entonces talves puedas usar `uptime -s`.

Comment: @CristianManuelAbalos Me parece que el comando `date` da la hora actual del sistema, el comando `uptime` indica la hora en que el servidor inició, pero no el tiempo desde que un usuario inició sesión.